# Angular4: RouterReuseStrategy and lazy loaded module route url

Tags: angular

I have a angular project where i want to create some sort of navigation menu. The idea is that all links of application is placed in top level NavigationComponent and other routes is a childs of it and loaded in router-outlet of it. The app routes became looks like that:

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    {
        path: '',
        component: NavigationComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'somepage', component: SomePageComponent },
            { path: 'module1', loadChildren: 'app/modules/module1.module#Module1Module' },
            { path: 'module2', loadChildren: 'app/modules/module2.module#Module2Module' },
        ]
    },
    // otherwise redirect to 404
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Now i want to add custom `RouterReuseStrategy`, but when i navigate to some route of child modules, that not loaded yet, i cant get future route url in `shouldReuseRoute()` method.

For example if i navigate to `'/module1/someRouteOfModule1'` in `routeConfig.path` of future route `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` will by only `'module1'`, and in `pathFromRoot` array there will not be other part of route either, and i cant correctly save that page.

But then, after that, app navigate to other route of that module, whole route can be received from pathFromRoute array and everything works fine.

Somebody encountered this problem? May be there is a way to preload lazy loading modules routes?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with lazy loading and resolved this by setting key for each route.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

       {path: "dashboard", loadChildren: "./dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule", data: { key: "dashboard" }},
,

];
```